# How to install a specific version of minikube on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, minikube

Both methods on the [official start page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) install the latest version. How can a specific version be installed either using homebrew or binary download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Binary:**
Go to the link below. Search for the version you want to install. Click on “Assets” of that version, Download the binary suitable for your macOS architecture. Install it.

sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases

**Homebrew:**
Go to the link below. Search for your version. Click on “view at this point in history”. Click on “Raw” and copy the url.

brew install “raw-url-link”

brew unlink minikube

brew link minikube

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/eaad48a89767c4fb7e4d80fcfacf24035844d3d0/Formula/minikube.rb

Comment: Only the binary worked. using raw url failed with this error `Invalid usage: Non-checksummed download of minikube formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported!  (UsageError)`

Comment: @daredadevil, which version are you trying to install?

Comment: i wanted the latest - 1.24 which comes with the latest kubernetes version (1.22). brew by default only installed the 1.21 for me. so i tried the raw url method but got that error instead.

Comment: also got the above, no good

Comment: Latest brew versions do not support installing formulae from a direct link. Download the formula locally and then install it.

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/cceca973c886f4af86d614f6363eae30efc9a49e/Formula/minikube.rb`

    and then

`brew install minikube.rb`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to spin up a specific version of kubernetes cluster, you can install the latest version of minikube and run a specific version of kubernetes cluster using `kubernetes-version` option.

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.21.0
```